get text from an editable div in html and move/show it in another html file
I am trying to get text that you type into a div with editable text to display on another html file, I'm trying to bring it from Format Test.html to display.html . Some context, I am making a little website that will only exist in my files, since it's only a little project I'm doing. I self-taught myself most of this stuff so I probably have a LOT of stuff wrong.
here are what I did in each of my files (don't mind the silly placeholders):
Format Test.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>ACNH</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <form action="display.html" method="GET">
    <div id="layer1">
      <p id="textl1">Checklist</p>
      <div id="layer2">
        <div id="layer3">
          <p id="textl3" contenteditable="true">teehee</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="2.html">
    <button onclick="go()">Send</button>
    </a>
    <script src="action.js"></script>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

display.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>ACNH</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="yayaya">RARARARRARARRARRARARRARARARRARARRA</p>
    <script src="action.js"></script>
    <script>disp();</script>
  </body>
</html>

action.js
function go() {
  var data = document.getElementById("textl3");
  localStorage.setItem("yaya ", data );
}

function disp() {
  document.getElementById("yayaya") = localStorage.getItem("textl3");
}



Are you loading these from local files or a webserver? When you use the file: URL scheme, each file has its own local storage. You need a webserver.

local files, not a webserver. Thank you for that insight, I want to use local files as its easier for what I'm doing, but good to know!
